# iOS, how to get subarray from an array using subarraywithRange

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, arrays

I am having problem with using subArrayWithRange.

Basically, what I want to do is make subarray of 50 elements or less from mainArray
for example if mainArray has 70 elements I want a sortedArray to have an array of first 50 elements in first index and another array of 20 elements in the last index of sortedArray

Hope I am clear what I want to do get.

anyway, my code is

```
for (int i=0; i<=ceilLoopCount; i++) {
    [sortedArray insertObject:[testArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,50)] atIndex:i]; 
}
```

and the problem I am having is I only get the same 50 elements in all the array

Please help,
Pondd

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSUInteger size = 50;

for (NSUInteger i = 0; i * size < [testArray count]; i++) {
  NSUInteger start = i * size;
  NSRange range = NSMakeRange(start, MIN([testArray count] - start, size));
  [sortedArray addObject:[testArray subarrayWithRange:range]];
}
```

Comment: Hi Thankz for help but I am getting Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: index 449 beyond bounds [0 .. 433]'
Not sure what you meant by "- loc"

Answer (score 0):

```
            NSMutableArray *arrayOfArrays = [NSMutableArray array];
            int batchSize = 30;

            for(int j = 0; j < [stuff count]; j += batchSize) {

                NSArray *subarray = [stuff subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(j, MIN(batchSize, [stuff count] - j))];
                [arrayOfArrays addObject:subarray];
            }
```